# AngularJS widget method is not available on latest AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run this slide on latest angular, but the widget method on angular object is deprecated
https://github.com/IgorMinar/ng-slides/blob/master/slide.js

Is there an updated version of this slides using the latest version?

What should I modify to make the angular.widget works on latest AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

`widget` was replaced with [`directive`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  I don't know how similar they are, but start with that name change.